# Outlook 2007 in Windows XP Mode when already have Outlook 2010 installed

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-xp-mode, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm running on Win7 Pro x64. I have Office 2010 x64 installed.

Company uses a plugin from Zantaz to archive emails and attachments. As far as i know, there is no x64 version or support for Outlook 2010 to date for this plug-in.

If i install Win 7's XP Mode, will i be able to install Outlook 2007 side by side with Outlook 2010? The 2007 version will be used only from within this XP Mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did install XP Mode for Windows 7. I then installed Outlook 2007 on it. Because Outlook 2007 is installed within the XP Mode VHD file, it is self contained within that virtual instance. So to answer my original question, is YES, this works.

I now can use either Outlook 2010 from my native Win 7 install or Outlook 2007 (with legacy plug-in) via XP mode and all works as expected.

Comment: That is exactly what XP Mode is for...

Comment: Correct. When I asked the question, I didn't realise XP Mode was just a glorified term for "virtual hard disk with Win XP". I thought the actual software was going to be installed on my host machine. All good.